# Xpages Mobile Categorized View

Tags: mobile, xpages

I have an xPage for mobile with the following Code

```
<xe:this.categoryColumn>
    <xe:viewCategoryColumn columnName="DC_SalesRep">
    </xe:viewCategoryColumn>
</xe:this.categoryColumn>
<xe:this.extraColumns>
    <xe:viewExtraColumn columnName="DC_CustomerName"
            style="font-size:8pt">
    </xe:viewExtraColumn>
</xe:this.extraColumns>
```

The column `DC_SalesRep` is categorized.

How can I hide the category title in the detail rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice that you haven't listed a Summary column. This is a required column. I would recommend using your extra column as the summary column and then if you want to provide a detail column, use the details facet. This should give you the outcome you're looking for. As for how this is all structured:

- DC_SalesRep (CategoryColumn - collapsible)

  - DC_CustomerName (SummaryColumn)

    - Any detail column you add as either a column or a facet should show up as a div of text in the same row as the summary
      column.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This did the job.